# Silly story where aliens cause everything inanimate (even shoes) to become intelligent and talk

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is another story I read in a science fiction magazine in the mid-to-late 1980s, probably published that decade.

The premise is silly: Aliens arrive at Earth and disapprove of the way that humans interact with their environment. They say something like "Everything has life." and depart. From that moment on, every distinct object is alive, and at least most have intelligence and can talk. (I believe that this scene is specifically described, as part of a flashback or exposition.)

The narrator describes what a trial it is to try to get through a day with everything you use having an opinion. One thing that stands out is that he mentions the complaints of his shoes. I think that, in the opening scene of the story, the narrator is standing or walking on the sidewalk, having a discussion or argument with one or both of his shoes (or perhaps just listening to a discussion or argument between them).

The tone of the story is tongue-in-cheek, not serious in any way.

**Update:** This is definitely not "The One-Shoe Blues" by Ron Wolfe; thanks to Richard for checking that possibility. Based on what I've been able to dig up online, it also doesn't seem to be either "When the Earth Lived" by Henry Kuttner or "I See a Man Sitting on a Chair, and the Chair is Biting His Leg" by Robert Scheckley and Harlan Ellison (though both suggestions are appreciated).

**Update 2**: I recently went through the table of contents for every issue of Asimov's from 1989 back on ISFDB, checking out every single title that seemed even a little bit promising. Unfortunately, I did not find this story - either it has a title with no recognizable link to its plot or it was published in another magazine. I have also managed to locate and read the two other suggestions ("I See a Man Sitting on a Chair, and the Chair is Biting His Leg" and "When the Earth Lived") and can definitively rule them both out.

**Update 3**: I've also found a copy of "The Short Happy Life of the Brown Oxford" and am certain that this is not that story, but the suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds similar to Phillip K. Dock's [*The Short Happy Life of the Brown Oxford,*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Short_Happy_Life_of_the_Brown_Oxford) but that was published in 1954.

Comment: @Joe L. - Interesting, but I don't think that's it. In this story, it's *everything* that comes to life, not just shoes.

Comment: Reminds me of Henry Kuttner's 1937 yarn ["When the Earth Lived"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57517), illustrated on the cover of [this](http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/a/a9/STARTLJUL1948.jpg) 1948 reprint, but of course that's not it.

Comment: "*He went to see a priest. The priest told him... he said it was alright and all that, when shoes are happy that they'd get into heaven. You see, it turns out [shoes have soles](http://randomhoohaas.flyingomelette.com/reddw/2/5.html)."*

Comment: This isn't "The One-Shoe Blues". That story is about a man speculating why there are so many single shoes found by the highway. He comes up with the hypothesis that there are one-legged aliens killing (and eating) hitchhikers and stealing their clothes, then chucking the unneeded shoe out of the window.

Comment: Reminds me of "I See a Man Sitting on a Chair, and the Chair is Biting His Leg" by Ellison and Sheckley (The Magazine of F&SF, Jan 1968) which concerns a man who is chased through a futuristic Las Vegas-like city by inanimate objects with an unnatural affection for him.

Comment: @ImaginaryEvents, I don't have a copy to read, but I don't think so... though I was hopeful because the premise does sound Sheckley-esque and the publication date and source seemed about right.

Comment: The premise sounds like Cliff Simak's "Skirmish," but the tone is all wrong.  Simak's story is most definitely _not_ tongue-in-cheek.  It was also first published in 1950.

Comment: @sigwv, I have read "Skirmish," and it's definitely not that story.