Short story about shoes that may have talked to other pairs of shoes and were possibly trying to find their owner or way home
I’m trying to find the name of a short story I read in the 1990s about shoes!
It came from a book of short stories, but I had only known it to have been photocopied, as it was a book from the library. It may have been a folklore story, but Google doesn’t seem to know.
The story only involved shoes; they may have talked to other pairs of shoes in the story. I can’t quite remember what the shoes were doing, possibly trying to find their owner or way home.

It might be worth looking at some of the references at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83604/silly-story-where-aliens-cause-everything-inanimate-even-shoes-to-become-intel but they don't look likely to me.

If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

This isn't an exact match, as it involves characters other than shoes, but in case you're misremembering: could it be The Short Happy Life of The Brown Oxford by Philip K. Dick?
It does involve shoes with their own agenda.
It was included in at least two anthologies of PKD stories, in 1985 and 1990, though was originally written in 1954.

Another possibility is "Shoes" by Robert Sheckley.
However, it was published in 2002, not the 1990s.
It's told in the first person -- by a man, not the sentient shoes.
But even when he is trying on the secondhand shoes in a Goodwill store, he hears a voice in his mind, "clear as a bell."
Before he has even identified the source of the voice, he hears, "You're not Carlton Johnson. Who are you?"
He answers with his name, and hears, "Well, you have no right to be wearing Carlton Johnson's shoes."
He actually argues with the shoes, and purchases them.
I can’t quite remember what the shoes were doing, possibly trying to find their owner or way home.
The shoes actually tell him, "That's because I'm still programmed to Carlton Johnson."
The shoes go on to say they are a prototype smart shoes, with micro-connections in the sole that pick up his sub-vocalizations, light-sensitive diodes in the eyelets, etc.
The shoes start "tweaking" the prescription on his eyeglasses so he can read better, almost instantly read the book he is reading, and keep suggesting actions he might take to improve his life.
They don't start yanking cigarettes out of mouths and cocktails out of hands as in some stories. But they do -- as he finds out retrospectively when his doorbell rings -- call up an old girlfriend and imitate his voice on the phone to ask her over.
It's a pretty short story. More humorous than dire.
When the woman comes over, since she is what he calls "a professional do-gooder", he hands her the shoes and tells her that these would be perfect for the right man.
He hustles her out with the shoes, telling her a deliberate lie, "Don't worry, I'll call."

The smart shoes from Red Dwarf?



The major point of similarity is the question's title. "...and were possibly trying to find their owner or way home."
In the story told by Lister, the shoes were given away, but they kept trying to return to their original owner.
If not this exact clip, it might have been some version of the same story.

This story, aside from having smart shoes, is nothing like the description.

I wouldn't say that. but I'll add some details showing the connection.

Hey Pete, I reckon you could be close, but then again it raises more questions than answers, they could have used the tale that I’m referring too and spun it a little to fit the episode’s storyline
